# Вывод символа в виде пикселей

Tags: c++, char, bmp

Начал изучение, пока что, голого C++. Всё что напишу ниже - это лишь глупая идея, которую хочется реализовать ради изучения языка. Сейчас тренируюсь на разборе/создании монохромного BMP-файла. Возник вопрос: можно ли как-то вывести символ в пиксельном представлении?

Т.е., условно, у нас есть картинка-сетка 32х32 пикселя. Символ, к примеру буква 'А', занимает 5х5 пикселей. Как мне сам символ можно перевести в сетку пикселей 5х5 без тупого условия

```
char ch = 'A';
if (ch == 'A')
{...} 
else if (ch == 'B')
{...}
```

И это ещё ладно обычные строки, а если широкие строки? Там символов жеж куууууча. Гугл что-то толком мне ничего не сказал

Comment: ну допустим нужно перевести, но из вопроса не понятно как должны выглядеть 5x5 - массивом?

Comment: условия делают тупыми люди) в конце концов есть понятие `структуры данных` и от них уже нужно плясать, меньше ифов будет

Comment: Мне вот без шуток интересно, если вы только начали изучать `c++`, то как сразу такие идеи приходят?

Comment: Ну а вообще я думаю можно с помощью `WinApi` это реализовать. Рисуем символ, а потом получаем биты и сохраняем в `bmp`. Что-то типа такого.

Comment: Есть библиотека libfreetype. Она только этим и занимается - по файлу шрифта создает массивы пикселей для букв.

Comment: Начнем с того, что понятие шрифта даже не упомянуто...

Comment: @ПавелЕриков
Ну, хочется сделать что-то более-менее полезное и интересное, а не простой калькулятор. Хотел попробовать вывести картинку, тем более разбор BMP - это неплохая тренировка работы с указателями и двоичными данными. Возможно глупо, сложно, но по-моему не совсем плохой вариант

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Обычно эта задача решается просто - отдельно хранится картинка с символами. По словам "font bitmap" можно найти много таких картинок с шрифтами (я не уверен в их лицензионной чистоте, поэтому, не копирую сюда явных ссылок).

Если присмотрится к таким картинкам, то там символы находятся в определенных позициях, которая очень легко может быть рассчитанная

```
char c = '?';// это нужный символ
int char_width = 8; // ширина символа, обычно 8 или 6 или кратное этому
int char_height = 8; // высота символа. обычно 8. бывает 12 или другое
int code = (int)c;
// нехитрой математикой расчитываем положение верхнего левого угла положения символа
// рассчитываем на то, что там все таки 16 символов в ряд. Но бывает по разному.
int left = (code % 16) * char_width;
int top = (code / 16) * char_height;
// а теперь копируем к нам. Да, попиксельно. Но нам для примера
// screen - массив "экрана"
// char_pos_x/char_pos_y - положение для вывода на экране
for (int x = 0; x < char_width; x++) {
  for (int y = 0; y < char_height; y++) {
     screen[x+char_pos_x][y+char_pos_y] = char_bitmap[x+left][y+top];
  }
}
```

Этот код с минимальными модификациями и оптимизациями используется везде для отрисовки моноширинных шрифтов (то есть, шрифтов, где и Ш и . занимают одинаковую ширину).

И если нужно вывести слово, то это просто в цикле выводятся буквы, не забывая смещать после каждой.

Есть шрифты, где ширина символа разная. Но в этом случае нам нужен небольшой массив, где хранится информация о том, где находится каждый символ и его ширина/высота. А дальше код сводится к коду выше.

А ещё есть векторные шрифты. Это уже сложнее. Там прям и написано (очень грубо конечно), что бы нарисовать букву ю, нужно нарисовать две палочки и эллипс/овал. Такие шрифты легко масштабируются и выглядят хорошо на разных экранах. А ещё в некоторых шрифтах есть возможность выполнять код (в виндовых шрифтах была такая уязвимость, но вроде ее прикрыли).